# Parameterizing Action and Partial view names throw ArgumentException error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, master-pages

Why would parameterizing Action and Partial view names throw ArgumentException error?

```
<div id = "Details" >

<% var ActionName = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"); %>
<% var PartialViewName = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"); %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm(ActionName, "ControllerName")) %>
        <% { %>
<%  Html.RenderPartial(PartialViewName, new List<Model>()); %>
        <% } %>

</div>
```

Changing it to following works:

```
<div id = "Details" >

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName")) %>
        <% { %>
<%  Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName", new List<Model>()); %>
        <% } %>

</div>
```

I get the follwoing error only when I parameterize Action and Partial view names:

```
Group with specified name "jQuery" already exists. Please specify a different name. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Group with specified name "jQuery" already exists. Please specify a different name.
```

On line 27:

```
Line 25:                  .Compress(true)
Line 26:         ).StyleSheets(styles =>
Line 27:             styles.AddGroup("jQuery", group =>
Line 28:                 group.DefaultPath("~/Scripts/css")
Line 29:                      .Add("start/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css")
```

View where Partial view is called from has Site.Master as its master view. Scripts, css are registered in Site.Master
Site.Master:

```
<%= 
    Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group =>
        group.DefaultPath("~/Content")
             .Add("Site.css")
             .Add("telerik.common.css")
             .Compress(true)
    ).StyleSheets(styles =>
        styles.AddGroup("jQuery", group =>
            group.DefaultPath("~/Scripts/css")
                 .Add("start/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css")
                 .Add("jquery.pnotify.default.css")
                 .Compress(true)
        )
    )
 %>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's your Action name? And, what's the name of the Partial View?

Comment: @ataravati Action & Partial View Name are same = "ShowDetails"

Comment: You have a different name in your code. Do you have your partial view inside a loop? The error you get does not seem to have anything to do with the action name. You are probably doing something wrong in some other part of the code.

Comment: @ataravati No, Partial view is not in a loop.

Comment: OK, please post the real code. Otherwise, it's not easy for others to be able to help you.

Comment: @ataravati Partial views are strongly typed and in a loop. Sorry for the earlier comment where I said otherwise. Would that be a reason I am getting this error?

Comment: Yes, remove the Telerik StyleSheet registrar out of the loop (put it in the main view or the parent partial view).